# Python class specific global attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, global-variables, metaclass

Lets say I have class `SuperModel`, `Model`, and `SubModel`.

I want to define a global attribute 'collection' that is the name of the class. For example, If I do:

```
Model.collection
```

it will return 'Model'.

If I subclass Model, say `class SubModel(Model)`

```
Submodel.collection
```

will return 'Submodel'

Is there a way to do so without explicitly rewriting the attribute for all the descendants of Model?

I was trying to get something out of metaclasses:

```
class SuperModel(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        if 'collection' not in attrs:
            attrs['collection'] = __name__.lower()

    return super().__new__(cls, name, base, attrs)

class Model(metaclass=SuperModel):
    pass
```

but when I try to subclass Model (for example `class SubModel(Model)`) I always get 'Model' when printing 'collection' when I'm expecting 'SubModel'.

**Edit:** I know there is a `__name__` attribute but what if I wanted to assign the `__name__` to a class variable each time the class is defined? So when subclassing Model there would be an attribute 'collection' in SubModel that equals `__name__` ('SubModel').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the **module global `__name__`** in your metaclass. That's neither the name of your metatype nor your class.

Your metaclass is handed the name of the new class already, in the `name` attribute. Simply use that:

```
class SuperModel(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        if 'collection' not in attrs:
            attrs['collection'] = name.lower()

    return super().__new__(cls, name, base, attrs)
```

Comment: I feel silly now that it's so obvious. By using `__name__`, 'metaclassing' SuperModel  in Model made `__name__` refer to 'Model'. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There already is such an attribute built in, and it is called `__name__`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> Foo.__name__
'Foo'
```